# Subclassing RKObjectManager multiple times

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

I have a subclass called `MyObjectManager` which inherits from `RKObjectManager`
in `MyObjectManager` I initialize RestKit (set base url etc etc)

I then subclass `MyObjectManager` into two different classes:
`UserManager` and `GameManager`.  Each implement different functions

at first I call `UserManager sharedManager` and it works fine. I later called `GameManager sharedManager` with a relevant function, but I get a "unrecognized selector sent to instance" error as it refers to the latter as a `UserManager`.

I read in the guidelines that it's accepted to subclass RKObjectManager several times, what am I missing?

MyObjectManager implementation:

```
static MyObjectManager *sharedManager = nil;

@implementation MyObjectManager

+ (instancetype)sharedManager {
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        NSString *baseUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://ip/api"];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:baseUrl];

        sharedManager = [self managerWithBaseURL:url];
        sharedManager.requestSerializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;

        [sharedManager setupRequestDescriptors];
        [sharedManager setupResponseDescriptors];
    });

    return sharedManager;
}
```

Comment: where sharedManager function is defined? In order to use GameManager sharedManager it must be defined in either in its class or in its superclass - MyObjectManager or RKObjectManager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `RKObjectManager +sharedManager` is a class method. It will instantiate the shared manager on first call and then return it on further calls. Your first call to `sharedManager` did instantiate a RKObjectManager and your call to `GameManager sharedManager` did return the same instance. This instance being of class RKObjectManager , it doesn't implement GameManager's functions - thus the *unrecognized selector sent to instance* error.

That's perfectly acceptable to subclass `RKObjectManager` but you should probably also subclass the class method `+sharedManager` inside `GameManager` to return your own static instance instead of relying on RKObjectManager's one.

EDIT : Based on your edit, you should try to subclass [+managerWithBaseURL](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKObjectManager.html#//api/name/managerWithBaseURL:) inside `GameManager` so that is returns an instance of `GameManager` instead of `RKObjectManager`.